# Autodownload and play ftp content - imagery

Tags: automation, ftp

This is my setup:

- 2 remote cameras upload via ftp a combination of jpg and mp4 images to a hosted server
- at our home I have a wall-display with a Raspberry Pi on HDMI

Goal:

- Loop-display continuously the last 24 hours of imagery, jpg and mp4 collated chronologically on a webpage
- content older then 48 hours should be deleted

I have some basic knowledge about scripting but mainly asking here what approach to take:

- assemble the video on the server every hour and download the updated video file in one go to the raspberry
  or
- download individual files to the raspberry and assemble video there?
  or
- tertiary software that could automate this?

As and added bonus, I also have a Synology NAS running at home, so that can be used as storage or processing too.

thanks for your input

G

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would need to point the server (ftp) to the local storage or home / internal IP (this could be custom too) and fetch the files from such IP or server into your web-page/home-display.

There are several ways to achieve this but ideally that is what would happen for you to have direct access and be able to display any files uploaded to the ftp server